# Program doesn't read but the 0 in array

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to do a program in java that reads integers between 1 and 100 and counts the occurrences of each. So I have first of all a Scanner to read from keyboard and an arrayList that we will store numbers in it. Then, in a WHILE loop I wrote the 2 conditions:
-To write integers only in "hasNextInt". 
-The second one to finish storing in array when the user print 0.
Finally I have a FOR loop to check whether each number is written more than once.
My code is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CountingOccurrenceOfNbs 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int count=1;
        int checker=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your numbers:");

        int num;       // integer will be stored in this variable
        num = input.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (input.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            while(num!=0)
            {
                num = input.nextInt();
                List.add(num);
                for(int i=0; i<List.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(num==checker)
                    {
                        count++;
                        System.out.println(num + " occurs " + count + " times");

                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Array has been filled completly");
        }
        System.out.println("Sorry! You entered a non-Integer value! Try again.");
    }
}
```

But the problem is that output is always like that:
0 occurs 2 times
0 occurs 3 times
0 occurs 4 times
and so on.

So what's the problem in my code!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 if(num==checker)
 {
     count++;
     System.out.println(num + " occurs " + count + " times");
 }
```

`checker` is always 0. Thus it is executed only when `num` is 0.

**EDIT**: As requested by OP.

There were multiple issues with your code, I will mention only some of them. First, you jumped over the first integer by calling scanner (reading) twice before writing once. Then there is no restriction on the range of input. `checer` is not modified. The last print line is not reached.

I used `HashMap` for the storing of the occurrences. Now it is printed once the loop is terminated, if you want to be in-loop you can try implement it yourself. Moreover, the code relies on valid input. That means that for say string would give an exception. That`s why you could check some condition for input to be integer and to throw an exception thereafter. Lastly, you should close the Scanner and free the memory.

```
import java.util.*;
public class YourClass 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your numbers:");

        int num;       // integer will be stored in this variable
        Map<Integer, Integer> list = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        num = input.nextInt();
        while (input.hasNextInt()){
            while(num != 0){
                if(!list.containsKey(num)){
                list.put(num, 1);
                } else {
                    int value = list.get(num);
                    list.put(num, ++value); //inc. before call, value++ wont work
                }
                num = input.nextInt();
            }
            for ( Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list.entrySet()) {
                Integer key = entry.getKey();
                Integer value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(key + " occurs " + value + " times");
            }
            System.out.println("Array has been filled completly");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //not reached
        System.out.println("Sorry! You entered a non-Integer value! Try again.");
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to java so I don't know the HashMap and containsKey

Comment: I know but can we solve this problem on the basic array declaration? (for example int[] array=new int[value])

Comment: Yes, you can use the first part for that matter of the CountingSort algorithm to count the occurrences and then iterate over and print only those ` != 0`

Comment: Firstly, you create an array for 99 elements [1..100] then initialize it with 0s(in java that is automatically done). The for the read number you check the index of the array to be equal to and then increment it. Lastly, you print all the indexes as values different from 0.

Comment: But my goal is to enter a random number of element not 99 element. I mean of "1-100" that each value can be between 1 and 100.

Comment: So if we can store in array a random number of numbers without specifying the size of that array

Comment: the size is specified - 100, the number of 1..100. You will increment the value of array[index], where index = number + 1.

Comment: If you have more understanding questions, please make a new question and close this one by accepting an answer or otherwise. Long discussions are not to be in the comments.

Comment: You didn't understand, I mean I want to create an array with a random number of integer, not 100 element (integer). That's it. In your solution, there's always 100 input I'm oblige to enter. For the " Long discussions are not to be in the comments", I have 11 reputation and to open this discussion as chat I must have at least 15 so this is a moderator job to switch it to chat. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, no, no. Your input can be arbitrary long. The only condition is the one imposed by you : integers between 1 .. 100. Then for every input you increment the value at the right position and the after finished reading input, you print the right positions. Then the index would be the number and the value at that index - the number of occurrences. See this for a visualization https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/CountingSort.html But imagine that the first "array" of the visualization is your input and and the second is the one you print after you had stopped reading. Anything unclear?

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand, you mean to write int[] myList=new int[99] first? If yes, this will store 100 element in this array. I want to write as many as I wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your numbers:");

    int sentinel = -1; // Type -1 to finish reading input.
    int x;
    while ((x = scanner.nextInt()) != sentinel)
        myList.add(x);

    scanner.close();

    // To show no duplicate frequency
    Set<Integer> uniqueInput = new HashSet<Integer>(myList);

    for (Integer i : uniqueInput) {

        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(myList, i);

        System.out.println(i + " occurs " + occurrences + " times");

    }

}
```

Comment: It's printing: 0 occurs 1 time. So it's operating the last number only.

Comment: I have the for inside the first while loop and outside the second one

Comment: Also put the for out of the first while too.

Comment: When I enter for example: 12 12 15 6 0, it's saying all of the numbers occur 1 times.

Comment: Program doesn't print anything if I put the for outside the first while.

Comment: I've made some changes, is it ok now?

Comment: no, I want to use the standard method of creating array not this                 [ Set<Integer> uniqueInput = new HashSet<Integer>(myList); ]